# Are my in-app purchases available for trial users of my app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-store

In the Windows Store for Windows 8, are my in-app purchases fully available for users of the trial version of my app? If not, will they be able to purchase the in-app purchases while still being on the trial version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694067.aspx):

> Note:  A customer can only make an in-app purchase if they've purchased
>   a full version of your app.

This doesn't prevent you from making your app free and then limiting what they can access until they make an in-app purchase to "upgrade" to the "full" version.